# Basic if statement won't execute properly

Tags: linux, bash

Hello I am trying to implement simple if statement in linux script however after executing it I get an error : [6: command not found - 6 is the number from input 
I added chmod +x and execute it : ./script

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "input number"
read number

if [$number>5]
then echo "number greater than 5"
fi
```

Comment: Spacing is important: `if [ $number>5 ]`.

Comment: wow and that make the whole difference thank you

Comment: Operators are important too. `>5` would redirect to a file named `5`.

Comment: should I use -gt then instead of > ?

Comment: Yup I tried it my scirpt print sth but at the same time I get an error no such file or directory when I changed it to -gt it works 100% fine now thanks

Comment: For integer comparison you should use `-gt`, > should be used for string comparison and should be escaped `\>`.